# How to use the Font.Underline property of an Excel 2007 chart element

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I'm trying to write some VBA code to copy the font style of one chart element to another in an Excel 2007 chart. Specifically, I'm trying to copy the font style from the ChartArea to the ChartTitle. I'm having a problem with the Font.Underline property.

No matter what the Underline property of the ChartArea is *set* to (e.q. xlUnderlineStyleSingle), the Underline property *returns* a value that does not match any of the XlUnderlineStyle constants (the value is 1745390344).

This is no doubt related to the fact that the UI for setting the font of a chart element is slightly different from the UI for setting the font of a cell on a worksheet.

For a cell, the UI shows only two underline styles (single & double) plus "none". This corresponds to the values in the XlUnderlineStyle enumeration.

For a chart element, the UI shows a whole bunch of underline styles including wavy lines etc. These are not represented in that enumeration.

So, I suspect that - for chart elements - there is actually another property that can be set, and the Font.Underline property is simply returning a "look elsewhere" value.

Can anyone tell me what that other property is called, and whether I can access that through VBA?

---

**EDIT** here's some code you can type directly into the immediate window to see the problem (select a chart first):

> ? ActiveChart.ChartArea.Font.Underline

Comment: What's the code you're using?  As far as I know the ChartArea itself doesn't have a font unless you mean `ChartArea.Format.Textframe2.TextRange.Font`.  Also, charts don't use the xlUnderline they use the `msoTextUnderlineType` enum.  However, none of those return 1745390344.  What's the fully qualified property that's returning that number?

Comment: @Banjoe: I've edited my answer. The ChartArea does have a font property - it's just "hidden", so you don't see any Intellisense for it until you type it in full. However, you've pointed me indirectly at the answer - the Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font object has an UnderlineStyle property that enumerates to msoTextUnderlineType. By all means submit that as an answer, and I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The msoTextUnderlineType enum is used in the ChartArea.Format.Textframe2.TextRange.Font.Underlinestyle property.